# Updating Duplicate records MySQL

Tags: mysql

Bellow is a screenshot of a table I have in my database, I want to insert a few products into that table but in the event a product already exists in the table I want it to update the quantity instead of inserting another row, so lets say I want to insert "Jelly Belly Harry Potter Jelly Slugs 2.1oz 12 CT" which already exists I would then want it to update the quantity from 2 to 3 and any products inserted that are not already in there to be added as a new row.

First time asking a question on here so I apologize if there is a mistake in my etiquette.
[Table Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kU7cc.png)

EDIT:

If you look at the Scan_id column that represents a customers order, so if i changed the last 3 items from scan_id 2 to 1 then those 3 items will be included in the other order, so there will be instances where I want duplicates in the name column as other orders that arent related may have that product on there, its when i want to merge orders that have the same products I just need to update the quantity.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html and check the related topics to the right of your screen under the ads

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please go through this link once: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: I did come accross that in my search for answers, however from what I understand (which may be wrong as im rather new to mysql) It only updates if theres a "duplicate value in a UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY", which in this instance isnt the case as the name column isnt unique or a primary key? or am i missing something ?

Comment: @MikeAbineri it seems that name is going to be unique only for your case, so you should add the UNIQUE constraint on the `name` column

Comment: @Mike Abineri How would you be able to detect a duplicate if it wasn't unique? Or is it that you don't want to create a unique key for some reason?

Comment: Well, if you look at the Scan_id column that represents a customers order, so if i changed the last 3 items from scan_id 2 to 1 then those 3 items will be included in the other order, so there will be instances where I want duplicates in the name column as other orders that arent related may have that product on there, its when i want to merge orders that have the same products I just need to update the quantity.

Comment: You are using terminology which only you know. What orders? - do scan_id represent an order? If you want to change something that already exists then you do so using an UPDATE statement why would you think that an INSERT would be appropriate?

Answer (score 1):

simply set the desired column to unique so as to prevent duplicates. What you is do an update instead of inserting the same values over and over again. I suggest you set the column to unique which means the values will be updated instead of being reinserted